# Use replace to change all occurrences

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code:

```js
var test = '1.200,0,0'
var test2 = teste.replace(',', '')
console.log(test)//1.200,0,0
console.log(test2)//1.2000,0
```

I would like to remove all "," from the string. How is this possible? Since with the replace he took only the first ","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```
var test = '1.200,0,0';
var test2 = teste.replaceAll(',', '');
console.log(test2) //1.20000;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression with `g` to match all occurrences.

```
"1,2,3".replace(/,/g,'');
---> "123"
```

Comment: Doubt ... I'm trying to use replaceAll () but the node's terminal returns me saying that replaceAll is not a function ...

I even copied the code that is not on the mozila's official website and returned it to me.

Comment: This answer doesn't use `replaceAll()`.  Maybe the comment belongs on the other answer?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method -- replace only replaces the first occurrence.

Comment: It's important to note that replaceAll is a very recent addition to JS. It might not work for your target audience. Take a look at the MDN docs for more details: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll